# Converting JSON returned from ASMX service to list of C# objects

Tags: c#, ajax, json, json.net

I am writing code to test `json` returned from an `asmx` web service in `C#`.  The returned response is in the following format:

```
{"d":"[{\"Id\":\"row1\",\"TheDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:00:00\",\"Description\":\"Test1\",\"Field\":\"N\"},     
       {\"Id\":\"row2\",\"TheDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:00:00\",\"Description\":\"Test2\",\"Field\":\"N\"}]
```

Eventually, I want to convert the data as a list of objects.  I'm constrained to use `JSON.Net`.

At the moment I am converting the `json` returned in the response to a `JArray` using the method below:

```
 private static JArray ConvertToJsonArray(StreamReader reader)
 {
     var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

     string result = json.Replace("{\"d\":\"", string.Empty);
     result = result.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
     result = result.Replace("]\"}", "]");

     return JArray.Parse(result);
 }
```

As you can see, I am doing a lot of manual formatting of the string so that it can finally be parsed.

I then loop round and take each `JObject` in the `JArray` and convert to the required object type before adding it to a list.

This does give me the desired results but I feel that there must be a more elegant solution.

Can anyone please help?

PS - I've left a lot of code out for brevity.  I can give more detail if required.

Comment: Do you have control over the asmx web service?  It looks like the results from that service are getting double serialized (this is why you have all those backslashes in there).  If you can fix the web service not to double serialize the response, then you will not have to do any massaging on the string before parsing it.  If not, then I'm afraid you don't have much choice.

Comment: I Agree with @Brian Rogers, it seems your manually serializing in the asmx.
Check this blog post for details:
http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: Thanks. Yes this seems to be the issue. I am not at the code now but will look later and update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Brian Rogers` and `Tanim Salem` (see comments above)

I did change the web service so that it not double serialized.

I can now simplify the code to something like this:

```
    private static JArray ConvertToJsonArray(string json)
    {          
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);                
        return (JArray)jsonObject["d"];
    }
```

And then convert it to my list of objects using:

```
    private static IList<ThirdPartyClaim> ConvertJsonArrayToListOfClaims(JArray jsonArray)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ThirdPartyClaim>>(jsonArray.ToString());           
    }
```

Any other comments or improvements would be appreciated.